# Character para Date

Tags: r

Considere a seguinte coluna data num data frame:

```
str(df$data)
 chr [1:2065986] "2021-09-28" "2021-06-17" "2021-09-08" "2021-06-09" "2021-09-23" "2021-08-04" "2021-09-29" "2021-06-09" "2021-09-29" ...
```

Como mudo de character para Data e no formato %d/%m/%Y?
Não tive êxito em nenhuma das formas abaixo:

```
as.Date(df$data, format= "%d/%m/%Y")

as.POSIXct(df$data, format= "%d/%m/%Y")

format.Date(df$data, format = "%d/%m/%Y") #ajusta no formato solicitado, mas continua character 

library(anytime)
anydate(df$data) #muda apenas para data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maneira mais simples de trabalhar com datas em diferentes formatos é usar o pacote lubridate, como indicado na [resposta de @neves](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/529925/117168). Esta resposta é para entender o que se passa com seu código.

A classe `Date` é definida como o número de dias a partir de uma referência. "%Y-%m-%d" é o padrão para *representar* datas, mas elas são armazenadas como números inteiros:

```
exemplo1 <- as.Date(c("28/09/2021", "17/06/2021"), format = "%d/%m/%Y")

str(exemplo1) # o 'format:' na saída indica que os valores exibidos foram formatados (veja ?print.Date)
#> Date[1:2], format: "2021-09-28" "2021-06-17"

dput(exemplo1)
#> structure(c(18898, 18795), class = "Date")
```

Quando indicado, o argumento `format` da `as.Date` é passado para `strptime` para indicar que a string de texto para conversão segue um formato diferente  do padrão internacional:

```
exemplo2 <- c(codigo.que.parece.data = "2021-09-10",
              data = "09/10/21",
              numero.inteiro = 18909)

as.Date(exemplo2)
#> [1] "2021-09-10" NA           NA

as.Date(exemplo2, format = "%d/%m/%y")
#> [1] NA           "2021-10-09" NA           NA
```

Pode usar `format` para armazenar as datas com uma representação específica, mas serão armazenadas como `character`:

```
exemplo3 <- c("21.09.28", "21.06.17", "21.09.08", "21.06.09", "21.09.23")

exemplo3.f <- format(as.Date(exemplo3, "%y.%m.%d"), "%d/%m/%Y")

str(exemplo3.f)
#>  chr [1:5] "28/09/2021" "17/06/2021" "08/09/2021" "09/06/2021" "23/09/2021"
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar `ymd` do *package* `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)

datas <- c("2021-09-28", "2021-06-17", "2021-09-08", "2021-06-09", "2021-09-23", "2021-08-04", "2021-09-29", "2021-06-09", "2021-09-29")

ymd(datas)

class(ymd(datas))

#[1] "Date"
```

Comment: Permaneceu no mesmo formato igual ao anydate  do anytime, em vez de mudar para "%d/%m/%Y":  Date[1:2054130], format: "2021-06-01" "2021-07-21" "2021-06-16" "2021-09-15" "2021-08-06" "2021-07-21" "2021-04-22" "2021-07-21" "2021-04-13" ...